# TF237090 when editing a globallist

Tags: tfs

I'm getting the following error when trying to add a new item to an existing global list in TFS:

```
Error saving Global list data:
TF237090: Does not exist or access is denied.
```

I get this error both using the TFS Power Tools from inside Visual Stuido and using the command line witadmin tool.  I do not get this error when adding items to other lists in the same TFS project.  What causes this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: As there is only one GlobalList catalog for a Collection and you have permission to add and remove items from lists within that catalog you must have a syntax issue. Can you post your xml?

Answer (score 0):

You must be a member of the Team Foundation Administrators group (or have equivalent permissions) in order to import the global list.

If I recall, the permissions necessary are:

- View collection-level information
- Edit collection-level information.

Ref: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404878%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thanks, but in my question you can see that I do have those permissions.  I'm able to modify other lists in the same project with no problems.